# How to return Redirect / View from Middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd want to ask about how to perform an redirect or just return view in my `HandleExceptionAsync` method

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext ctx)
{
    try
    {
        await next(ctx);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await HandleExceptionAsync(ctx, ex, next);
    }
}

private static async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex, RequestDelegate next)
{        
    Notify(ex.Message);

    var result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "CustomError" };

    ??
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I am doing as follows:

```
context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
```

Where `Home` and `Error` are the controller and action name respectively.